# How to get sysprocesses.program_name for current connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I need to retrieve the value of `sysprocesses.program_name` for the current connection. I use Sql Server 2008R2.

In other words i would like to join `sysprocesses` to this

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
where session_id = @@SPID
```

But i am not succeeding.

Just to explain the context:

I need to know `program_name` of the current session because the application i am working on writes info about who is logged in into the system (it does not depend on sql serveer user, because `sa` is used for connection) into `program_name` (it is a trick).
If I could read `program_name` i would be able to implement some custom logic into a `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger i am writing.

i am twaking a legacy application by working on triggers only (it is "emergency maintenance").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [this builtin function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx):

```
    select app_name()
```

Alternatively, you can use this query to get more than only the name of the program:

```
    select  *
    from    sys.[dm_exec_connections] as [dec]
            inner join [sys].[sysprocesses] as [sp] on [dec].[session_id] = [sp].[spid]
    where   [dec].[session_id] = @@SPID
```

Comment: The builtin function is even better, in fact it is the only thing i need. Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `sysprocesses.program_name` is equivalent to the return value of `APP_NAME()` for the given connection? Is there any evidence for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ant_22: yes you can see Application Name if you add "Application Name" in connection string, exemple to see how many connections per process:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    PROGRAM_NAME as ProgName,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0 
GROUP BY 
    dbid, PROGRAM_NAME, loginame
```